# Unexplainable arduino bug

Tags: arduino

I have a crazy problem. I'm reading data from a transmitter on a receiver on an Arduino in the following format: Start_Byte data%256 , data/256

This allows me to send a 2 byte int. The crazy thing is that unless I println -257 *after* I receive the code and check the comma, then it doesn't work, even if it just prints -257 it won't work.

```cpp
#define START_BYTE 'J'

// Receives an int over the RF network
int recieveData(void){

  int val;     // Value of the int

  //Wait for the data, then the Start_Byte
  while(Serial.available() == 0);

  while(Serial.read() != START_BYTE);


  val      =  Serial.read();
  char c   =  Serial.read();
  val     +=  Serial.read()*256;

  if(c == ','){
    Serial.println("************");
   Serial.println(val);
  }

  Serial.println(-257);


  return val;
}
```

This is the result I get if I add the -257:

```
-257
-257
-257
-257
-257
-257
-257
-257
************
<Correct data>
-257
************
<Correct data>
-257
************
<Correct data>
-257
************
<Correct data>
-257
************
```

If I don't add the -257, then I get nothing.

If I try anything else then it just prints that.

Comment: Random guess:  integer overflow?  Have you verified using pencil-and-paper that everything you're pushing into `val` will actually fit?

Comment: Yeah, checked that, its only transmitting small numbers anyway

Comment: Right.  How small is small?  Isn't the arduino default `int` 16-bit?  Given that it's signed, the largest values you could be sending across the wire are 126 and 127.

Comment: Firstly I'm just trying to send values <20, secondly I was pretty sure I could send much larger values. I've done this before and was able so send values much larger than 10,000.

Comment: Edit the question to describe what is the result you are seeing and why you think it is crazy.

Comment: I'm afraid I've not got any other theories, then.  Perhaps you could try attaching a scope to the actual PIN and see what you're transmitting?  `-257` is a very suspicious magic value (it's all 1s?).

Comment: I've checked the transmitter and every thing is ok on that side, its the receiver that the problem.

Comment: what code/software do you use on the host side to read arduino's serial output?

Comment: Just the standard Arduino Serial output at the top right of the IDE

Comment: Are you sure there is a "," in the data from the receiver? - Seems strange to me to insert an ASCII "," in between binary data. - If/when the "," is not found nothing will be printed obviously. - What's the value of the start byte? Could it appear in one of the data bytes?

Comment: replace your   Serial.println(-257); with a nice "Serial.flush();"

Comment: Also could you give us a link to the datasheet for the "crazy" device.

Comment: int val = Serial.read(); This gives the numerical value of the ASCII character received, to get the integer value, use: int val = Serial.Read() + '0'; Your string sent: "J<data>%256,<data>*256", what does that translate into with a number like <data> = 5 for example? 5%256 = 5, 5*256 = 1280, so the string is "J5,1280". Or am I misunderstanding the way you send the data string?

Comment: Sorry I should have made it more clear. When I transmit the data I send it as data%256 , data/256.

Comment: @Gian - no - You don't have to guess such things. - click Start, type c a l c, select Calculator. Select menu View - choose Programmer.  Click radio button "Dec".  Type 2 5 7 - .  See bits

Comment: Just to be certain.  You are showing that the println(-257) initially emits "-257", then changes to emit "-275".

Comment: @jdr5ca, perhaps I was unclear.  `-257` is not going to fit into a byte.  I was speculating as to how the overflow behavior might manifest using this particular toolchain on this particular architecture, rather than guessing at the arrangement of bits in the value `-257` (although that's a fun game too, given that myriad of encoding schemes in existence!). Your condescension isn't really helpful.

Comment: I fixed the 257 275 thing sorry, I have no idea how that happened